# Google Firebase signin giving status 12501 (not working), in release build variant and jks SHA

Tags: android, firebase, release, sha1, google-signin

**I know this question has been asked by many and have been answered.**

So, why am I asking this question again? Cuz I tried those solutions, and I did followed Google docs, followed tutorials and youtube. Still no luck.

Oright, this is what I did in my project.

**Project:** GoogleSignIn

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
      }
```

Gradle (Module: app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'alias'
            keyPassword 'keypass'
            storeFile file('/home/reoxey/path/to/jks')
            storePassword 'storepass'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "reoxey.com.googlesignin"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.8.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

LoginActivity.java

```
gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.web_client_key))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this, this)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();

        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
                startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN){
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            if (result.isSuccess()){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Nailed it",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else {
                Snackbar.make(mLoginFormView,result.getStatus().toString(),Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Messed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }
    }
```

string.xml

```
<string name="web_client_key">123456789-clientwebapplication.apps.googleusercontent.com</string>
```

There is no special configuration in manifest, and I believe that I am not missing anything there.

google-services.json

```
{
  "project_info": {
    "project_number": "{numeric-id}",
    "firebase_url": "https://project--123456789.firebaseio.com",
    "project_id": "project--123456789",
    "storage_bucket": "project--123456789.appspot.com"
  },
  "client": [
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "1:{numeric-id}:android:sfdjgsdkdfgsfs",
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "reoxey.com.googlesignin"
        }
      },
      "oauth_client": [
        {
          "client_id": "{numeric-id}-androidkey.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          "client_type": 1,
          "android_info": {
            "package_name": "reoxey.com.googlesignin",
            "certificate_hash": "{sha1-from-jks-file}"
          }
        },
        {
          "client_id": "{numeric-id}-webapplication.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          "client_type": 3
        }
      ],
      "api_key": [
        {
          "current_key": "{android-key}"
        }
      ],
      "services": {
        "analytics_service": {
          "status": 1
        },
        "appinvite_service": {
          "status": 2,
          "other_platform_oauth_client": [
            {
              "client_id": "{numeric-id}-webapplication.apps.googleusercontent.com",
              "client_type": 3
            }
          ]
        },
        "ads_service": {
          "status": 2
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "configuration_version": "1"
}
```

Oright, now Firebase console.

- **created project with package name**
- **added sha1 fingerprint generated from jks file**
- **enabled authentication for google signin**

that's it I guess, hope I provided everything,
so what am I missing here.

When I click on google sign, it gives me an error with **12501** status code. I don't know what's wrong here. Anyone?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you built a debug APK and tried the sign-in with it?

Comment: obviously, but different sha1 fingerprint

Comment: Did that fail with the same status?

Comment: It is working fine in debug. but not in release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are adding all the SHA-1 Finger prints in firebase still you are getting error.then (I was facing this problem. after this steps it's resolved.)Try this steps:

1.Go to Google Console API credentials Page.

2.Click the credentials in the Left tab.

3.Already two default Android and Web OAuth client Id will be present. You have to create One Android Client and One Web 2.0 Client.

4.Go to Firebase.In project setting ,download google-services.json and paste in app folder.

(Everything is fine but still you are cannot signin google means maybe OAuth problem. so make sure to create Android and Web client ID.Finally in credential page you have 2 Android Client and Two Web client Id.)

Fill the OAuth Content Screen also

Answer (score 1):

When you build your `GoogleSignInOptions`, you use string resource `web_client_key`.  For security reasons, you didn't post the real key and instead used example value `123456789-clientwebapplication.apps.googleusercontent.com.`.

That example value does not appear in the posted `google-services.json`, so I cannot match it with the values there.  The value should be the `client_id` defined in this block:

```
{
  "client_id": "{numeric-id}-webapplication.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "client_type": 3
}
```

Is that the value you used?

The [conventional way](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/auth/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/auth/GoogleSignInActivity.java#L81-L84) of getting the web client ID is to use string resource `R.string.default_web_client_id`, which is generated by the [Google Services Gradle Plugin](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin#processing_the_json_file) from `google-services.json`.  Is there a reason you cannot do that and must define your own string resource?  Have you tried using `default_web_client_id`?

Comment: yes,  `client_id` in string is matching with google-services.json and, I quite aware of `default_web_client_id`. Also tried it. And it doesn't work.

Comment: I had same problem as above, but its not the problem with configuration. It seems to be problem of ISP providers. I tried with different ISP providers and it seems to work then.